# How do I use another column if two rows in the first column checked are the same?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks something like this:

#### stones

| ID | number | snumber | wt | qt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a |  | 11.5 | 13 |
| 2 | c |  | 4.0 | 8 |
| 3 | a | a1 | 1.0 | 2 |
| 4 | d |  | 0.5 | 1 |
| 5 | b |  | 2.0 | 4 |
| 6 | a | a2 | 5.0 | 1 |
| 7 | f |  | 3.0 | 6 |
| 8 | a | a3 | 5.0 | 10 |

How do I select all from **stones** and if the column *number* has rows in the column *snumber* only give results from *snumber*'s rows [otherwise use *number*]?

I am also trying to incorporate in my previous [working] code that selects all rows in the table that *wt* >= 2.5 then count all those rows as *totalrows*:

```
SELECT inv.*, COUNT(*) OVER() AS totalrows FROM stones inv WHERE wt >= 2.5
```

- So from the example above, I'd want to show the following rows **c**,  **a2**, **f** and **a3** with *totalrows* = 4:

| ID | number | snumber | wt | qt | totalrows |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | c |  | 4.0 | 8 | 4 |
| 6 | a | a2 | 5.0 | 1 | 4 |
| 7 | f |  | 3.0 | 6 | 4 |
| 8 | a | a3 | 5.0 | 10 | 4 |

### Failed Attempt

I tried these, but I'm getting an error with my PHP so I'm assuming there's a problem with the SQL:

#### 1st

```
SELECT stones.*,
 CASE 
  WHEN x.totalrows > 1 
   THEN stones.snumber
   ELSE stones.number
  END AS numberORsnumber
  FROM stones 
  JOIN (
   SELECT number, COUNT(*) AS totalrows FROM stones
    GROUP BY number
  ) x ON x.number = stones.number
WHERE x.totalrows = 1 OR stones.snumber <> '' AND wt >= 2.5
```

#### 2nd

```
SELECT inv.*, COUNT(*) OVER() AS totalrows FROM stones inv 
 CASE 
  WHEN totalrows > 1
   THEN inv.snumber
  ELSE inv.number
 END AS number
WHERE wt >= 2.5
```

Comment: See COALESCE () and use NULL for blank values

Comment: @Strawberry I was actually just looking at that but I want to use _number_ unless other rows with that _number_ have _snumber_ in which case only use that _snumber_ and not the "master" _number_. I couldn't figure out how to check that with `COALESCE()`.

Comment: The 2nd attempt is wrong. You were doing `FROM stones inv` to `CASE ..`. It should be the other way around. If the `CASE` expression moved to `SELECT`, you can't actually use `totalrows` in the operation. Unless you're making it as a subquery then uses `totalrows` in outer query `SELECT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is at `END AS number OR snumber`. After you remove `OR snumber`, there won't be any error but there won't be any result too; against the example data you've provided. Try changing `WHERE x.totalrows = 1 AND wt >= 2.5` to `WHERE wt >= 2.5` only because you're already doing a `CASE` expression:

```
CASE 
        WHEN x.totalrows > 1
            THEN stones.snumber
            ELSE stones.number
        END AS number
```

So adding `WHERE x.totalrows = 1` won't yield anything from the `CASE`.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e16a371245d2da96a348e5cd20bc707)

**Update:**

Well, after long discussion in comment, I think I got it:

```
SELECT inv.ID, 
       CASE WHEN inv.snumber <> "" 
            THEN inv.snumber ELSE inv.number 
            END AS numberORSnumber, 
       inv.wt,
       inv.qt,
       COUNT(*) OVER() AS totalrows,
       CASE WHEN inv.number=v.number 
            AND inv.snumber="" THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Checking
FROM stones inv 
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT number FROM stones WHERE snumber <> "" group by number) v
WHERE wt >= 2.5
HAVING Checking <> 0
ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

I end up adding a `CROSS JOIN` with a subquery that return `number` value that have `snumber` as per OP requirement. Then with that, I use `CASE` to do the checking and finally use `HAVING` to filter them out from the checking.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=40cb88da028a42dc147dc4224154ab05

Comment: Woah, thats pretty much what I want! Is there any way to combine counting _totalrows_ with the rest of the SQL though?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The condition of `wt >= 2.5` pretty much restrict the results to that condition at the moment. Are you trying to return everything from the `stones` table and add additional columns from query results? A `LEFT JOIN` maybe? Can you edit you question and post your expected output? thanks

Comment: I added another table to the body of the question explaining what I want. Thanks for your time by the way

Comment: Actually the count results are all `5`.. and I think `wt >= 2.5` can't be use here. How to get the count=6?

Comment: OMG I'm so sorry about that. I fixed it to the correct desired results. I did it too quick. Is there no way to do this? I also have to add a few `AND`s after the `wt >= 2.5`.

Comment: It's ok, I think you just want the `totalrows` column to be shown in the result right? Maybe like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6bd3b218de8d2628e36dfc8b5304e3d2

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I've been trying to do but when I add something to the end for example `AND qt > 4`, _totalrows_  remains 5. I also don't want to show the row _a_ (without _snumber_) as the rows _a_ with _snumber_ are showing

Comment: Well, the `totalrows` was coming from the subquery so adding condition in the outer query doesn't affect anything from the sub-query itself.

Comment: I know I'm killing you but in your [updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=10566a896ca72687448d79ea159564cb) I just don't want the _number_ to show if the _snumber_ is showing. The reason is that if a _number_ has a _snumber_ that same _number_ that doesn't have the _snumber_ is an accumulation of all its _snumber_. I REALLY APPRECIATE ALL THE HELP YOU'RE DOING!! THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME

Comment: So you're saying that even if only one `snumber` occurring in the result, you don't want to show all other `number` except for `snumber` but if there's none `snumber` then show all the `number`?

Comment: Thats exactly what I want, all while counting all the results (_totalrows_)

Comment: something like this perhaps? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ac5d1970807cdf528b364c1906e5d30

Comment: No I want it to have the _number_/_snumber_ column but if a row with the _number_ has another row with an _snumber_ I don't want to have the row with the _number_.

So the entire row for _ID 1_ wouldn't show because it has the same number as _ID 3_, _ID 6_ and _ID 8_ but doesn't have an _snumber_

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it. So the expected result in your question is still the one you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah, the table right before my "Failed Attempts"