# Simple MySQL Insert Query with string comparison condition

Tags: mysql, insert

I want to insert a row into a table based on some condition that needs to be in the query itself.

Let's say I have two tables `foo` and `bar`. Each have an `id` column.

Now I have a third table `myTable` that can have a foreign key to either `foo` or `bar` but not to both.

**myTable**

```
+----+------+--------+--------+
| id | data | foo_id | bar_id |
+----+------+--------+--------+
|  1 | one  |  NULL  |   5    |
|  2 | two  |   7    |  NULL  |
+----+------+--------+--------+
```

When I insert into `myTable` it should have a foreign key in **either** foo_id **or** bar_id **but not** both... as shown in the table above.

Here are some of the queries I've tried to handle the **either/or** condition, but I can't seem to get it right. I've checked multiple threads and my queries seem to to match the answers there. `$my_string` is a session variable a use to keep track of which column to insert in... its values are either 'foo' or 'bar'

```
INSERT INTO myTable (data, if($my_string = foo,foo_id,bar_id)) values ('three',$id);
```

```
INSERT INTO myTable (data, (CASE WHEN $my_string IS foo THEN foo_id ELSE bar_id)) VALUES ('three',$id);
/*replacing the IS with an = doesn't change the outcome*/
```

I've also tried variations of adding quotes around the strings and removing them but they don't seem to change the outcome. I won't show all the variations to keep the question as short as possible

When I remove the condition part and only insert the `data` column the query functions properly... so I'm certain the condition is what's causing the issue.

**EDIT**

I'm **not** trying to add a constraint. I'm not afraid I'll add two values to `foo_id` and `bar_id`... I won't ever do that in any part of my application.

I have a two session variables `$id` and `$my_string`. I want an insert query that says: "If `$my_string` = 'foo' then insert `$id` into the column `foo_id`. Otherwise insert `$id` into `bar_id`".

I hope this clarifies the issue. Many thanks to those who answered already and helped clear this ambiguity.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65912042/how-do-i-use-another-column-if-two-rows-in-the-first-column-checked-are-the-same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your unspecified application language to use `foo` or `bar` as the column name when it creates the SQL;

so in a made up language:

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (data, ${my_string}_id ) VALUES ('three', ?)";
  $ps = prepare($sql);
  $ps->execute($id);
```

Comment: I had php as a tag but someone edited it out. This solved the problem but I'd still like to see how to do it with SQL. If no one replies I'll best answer this one. Thank you

Comment: MySQL's [insert syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) doesn't support a dynamic specification of column names (same applies to all syntaxs I can think of).

Comment: Please forgive a beginner's question... but why do SELECT statements support "dynamic specification of column names" while INSERT statements don't? I've used CASE statements successfully in SELECT statements so I just thought INSERT statements would function similarly.

Comment: The results in a `SELECT` statement are expressions. In the syntax for `INSERT` they are specified as column names. In a sense `select` expressions are evaluated every row returned, however `INSERT` isn't setup to dynamically change which columns its inserting into.

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL 8+, you could implement this logic via a check constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT my_check
CHECK (foo_id IS NULL AND bar_id IS NOT NULL OR
       foo_id IS NOT NULL AND bar_id IS NULL);
```

Comment: This would be a nice addition, but sadly does not answer my question. I need to know **which** column to enter the $id in. I don't believe a constraint will help me do that

Comment: Your comment does not make any sense.

Comment: what don't you get? I have a variable (integer) called $id that's equal to the PK of a row in either ```foo``` or ```bar```. I need to know at runtime which column to insert to $id in... so I'm trying to use a condition. What's so hard to understand?

Comment: Someone else suggested the same solution. My question might be misleading so I'll probably post a rephrased version that better emphasizes the issue.